# Usar Jquery & Angular de manera hibrida

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

Tengo una duda, espero y puedan ayudarme. 
Tengo una función `jquery` que estoy usando en ***angular***, es para generar datatable... el punto es que dentro de la función no puedo usar `router.navigate[enlace];`

```
     $('#example tbody').on( 'click', '.btn-detalle', function fun () {           
       var data = tabla.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        var id = data[0];
        localStorage.setItem('actionId',id);
        this.router.navigate(['inicio/editUser']);
    });
```

esta es la función que me gustaría poder usar; no uso `window.location.href(enlace)` por que pierde la carga reactiva.

Espero y puedan orientarme, saludos!!!!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español Xavi, consejo No uses jQuery. Añadir en tu template un binding `(click)="metodo($event)"` es muy sencillo. Refactoriza el código y evita esas pesadillas en el futuro.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo curioso es que con jquery no reconoce el metodo (click), uso jquery porque son los requerimientos que me estan pidiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Eh encontrado el error, para poder usar

```
this.router.navigate[(ruta)];
```

es necesario declarar this de la siguiente manera

```
 declare that=this;
```

eso quiere decir que el código quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
 that.router.navigate([ruta]);
```

quiere decir que ya se puede usar de ésta manera:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', '.btn-detalle', function () {
    var data = tabla.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    var id = data[0];
    localStorage.setItem('actionId',id);

    console.log(id);
    that.router.navigate(['inicio/editUser']);
});
```